# Check if a fact has been entered into a Prolog knowledge base

Tags: prolog

If I have a query that's executing of the form:

```
human(mary)
```

How can I find out if `mary` has ever been entered in any other predicate previously. In other words, how can I tell if the knowledge base has seen Mary before?

Comment: Do you mean if human(mary) exists? Or mary in any other context?

Comment: `Mary` is a variable. So I assume you mean `human(mary)`? If it occurs more than once, then `human(mary)` will succeed more than once. If you did, `findall(t, human(mary), L), length(L, Number)` then `Number` would be the number of times `human(mary)` was true.